# Step value in spinner box in HTML increasing minimum and not step at first increase

Tags: html, angular

In my `HTML` file, I have the following code:

```html
<mat-form-field class="generate-full-width">
    <input matInput type="number" min="100" max="1000000000" step="1000" name="elements"
        formControlName="elements" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" placeholder="Max Elements"
        numbersOnly>
    <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && hasError('elements', 'required')">Max Elements is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

This value is dependent on another field, a drop-down box called Product. The issue is:
For product ABC, the value of `elements` starts at 100 and goes up in increments of 1000, which is working fine.

However, for product DEF, the value of `elements` starts at 10,000(or 100,000) for another product and while increasing the value, the first increment is of 100 and not 1000. I thought that is because of `min="100"` validation in HTML.

Removing `min="100"` validation solves it, but then the product ABC doesn't start with 100 but with 1000. The step value cannot be 100. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Update your minimum value to:
min=elements[0]